# program isnt working because of an error in y

Tags: matlab

this is my program, its supposed to get an input from the user for the starting x value, stepping value, and an ending x value, the user also inputs the y function he likes, the graph is then supposed to graph it but i keep getting an error, any ideas?

```
clear all ; % clear memory
close all ; % close any open figures
drawnow ; % update screen now
clc ; % clear screen


display('** Welcome to Plotting Program **') ;
display(' ');

start=input('please enter starting x value:');
step=input('please enter ending x value:');
stop=input('please enter step value:');

y= double(input('please input your equation:'));

x=double(start:step:stop);


plot(x,y);
```

Comment: What is the error? add it to your post

Comment: You need to *evaluate* the provided expression at each data point in `x`.  But why would anyone use a script like this when just typing expressions into MATLAB would be easier.

Comment: the error is Error using input
Undefined function or variable 'x'.

Error in HW9 (line 14)
y= input('please input your equation:'); and we have to use a script in order to submit it

Comment: You are trying to have matlab interpret y as a symbolic function. Matlab is not made for that stuff, it is not like Maple or Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str2func()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) to convert string input into a function handle:

```
y = input('Input only the RHS of your equation as a function of ''x'' and enclose in '': ')
y = str2func(['@(x)' y]);
plot(x,y(x))
```

Also note that `double(start:step:stop)` will not work, since you are converting chars to their ASCII mapping:

```
double('20')
ans =
    50    48
```

Use instead `str2double(input('...'))`

Comment: I wanted to suggest this as well (@(x)<function>), however what you have written down for 'y' might not work, since I think the input wouldn't be interpreted as a string. So you might want to add this:
`y = input('<text>','s')`
And I am assuming that he will not enclose the inputs values with '' in which case the inputs will already numerical values (either integers or double).